# triggering multiple css animations with one click

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Link named "collection's" should be the one to launch all animations below. At the moment animations go just as I want when I refresh the page. How do I change trigger from refreshing/starting the page to the click? Dont mind my messy html, just need to know how to trigger these animations with click...

```
                <div class="menu-hover">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h1>Season</h1>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="menu-hover">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h1 class="trigger">Collection's</h1>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="menu-hover">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h1>My account</h1>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>

            <a href="#">
                <h2 id="sub1" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInLeft">For me</h2>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <h2 id="sub2" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInRight">Furry friend</h2>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <h2 id="sub3" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInLeft">Ambient</h2>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <h2 id="sub4" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInRight">Home</h2>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <h2 id="sub5" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInLeft">DustOnLens</h2>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <h2 id="sub6" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInRight">Tilbehöör</h2>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <h2 id="sub7" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInLeft">Coolio</h2>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <h2 id="sub8" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInRight">?Mystery?</h2>
            </a>

        </div>
```

animations are timed with css like this.

```
    /* animations */
#sub1{
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

#sub2{
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

#sub3{
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

#sub4{
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

#sub5{
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

#sub6{
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

#sub7{
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

#sub8{
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
```

Comment: use `classList.toogle` to add and remove a `class` ie:. `.sub8,.sub8.active{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a simple `onclick` event handler to the designated `h2` element that will assign ( toggle ) a particular class to the elements that you wish to animate. If the initial `animation-play-state` is set to `paused` you can assign, in the new class, a value of `running` to start the animations.

Not knowing all the CSS classes used or wishing to write out multiple classes for animations the below uses a very simple animation for all elements ~ you will have to substitute your real animations.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Trigger CSS Animations by clicking link</title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                document.querySelector('.trigger').addEventListener('click',()=>{
                    Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( '.animated' ) ).forEach( div=>{
                        div.classList.toggle('activated')
                    })
                });
            })
        </script>
        <style>
            .animated{
                animation-play-state:paused;
            }
            .activated{
                animation-play-state:running
            }

            .bounceInLeft,
            .bounceInRight,
            .bounceInLeft,
            .bounceInRight,
            .bounceInLeft,
            .bounceInRight,
            .bounceInLeft,
            .bounceInRight{
                opacity:1;
                color:black;
                font-size:1.5rem;

                animation-duration:2s;
                animation-name:geronimo;
                animation-direction:normal;
                animation-fill-mode:forwards;
                animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                animation-timing-function: linear;
            }


            @keyframes geronimo{
                from{opacity:1;color:black}
                50%{color:red}
                to{opacity:0;color:blue;}
            }




            /* animations */
            #sub1{
                animation-delay: 0s;
            }
            #sub2{
                animation-delay: 0.1s;
            }
            #sub3{
                animation-delay: 0.2s;
            }
            #sub4{
                animation-delay: 0.3s;
            }
            #sub5{
                animation-delay: 0.4s;
            }
            #sub6{
                animation-delay: 0.5s;
            }
            #sub7{
                animation-delay: 0.6s;
            }
            #sub8{
                animation-delay: 0.7s;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <div class="menu-hover">
                <a href="#">
                    <h1>Season</h1>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-hover">
                <a href="#">
                    <h1 class="trigger">Collection's</h1>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-hover">
                <a href="#">
                    <h1>My account</h1>
                </a>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div>
            <a href="#"><h2 id="sub1" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInLeft">For me</h2></a>
            <a href="#"><h2 id="sub2" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInRight">Furry friend</h2></a>
            <a href="#"><h2 id="sub3" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInLeft">Ambient</h2></a>
            <a href="#"><h2 id="sub4" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInRight">Home</h2></a>
            <a href="#"><h2 id="sub5" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInLeft">DustOnLens</h2></a>
            <a href="#"><h2 id="sub6" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInRight">Tilbehöör</h2></a>
            <a href="#"><h2 id="sub7" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInLeft">Coolio</h2></a>
            <a href="#"><h2 id="sub8" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInRight">?Mystery?</h2></a>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
document.querySelector('.trigger').addEventListener('click',()=>{
 Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( '.animated' ) ).forEach( div=>{
  div.classList.toggle('activated')
 })
});
})
```

```css
.animated{
 animation-play-state:paused;
}
.activated{
 animation-play-state:running
}

.bounceInLeft,
.bounceInRight,
.bounceInLeft,
.bounceInRight,
.bounceInLeft,
.bounceInRight,
.bounceInLeft,
.bounceInRight{
 opacity:1;
 color:black;
 font-size:1.5rem;
 
 animation-duration:2s;
 animation-name:geronimo;
 animation-direction:normal;
 animation-fill-mode:forwards;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
}


@keyframes geronimo{
 from{opacity:1;color:black}
 50%{color:red}
 to{opacity:0;color:blue;}
}




/* animations */
#sub1{
 animation-delay: 0s;
}
#sub2{
 animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
#sub3{
 animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
#sub4{
 animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
#sub5{
 animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
#sub6{
 animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
#sub7{
 animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
#sub8{
 animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="menu-hover">
  <a href="#">
   <h1>Season</h1>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="menu-hover">
  <a href="#">
   <h1 class="trigger">Collection's</h1>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="menu-hover">
  <a href="#">
   <h1>My account</h1>
  </a>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <div>
 <a href="#"><h2 id="sub1" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInLeft">For me</h2></a>
 <a href="#"><h2 id="sub2" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInRight">Furry friend</h2></a>
 <a href="#"><h2 id="sub3" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInLeft">Ambient</h2></a>
 <a href="#"><h2 id="sub4" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInRight">Home</h2></a>
 <a href="#"><h2 id="sub5" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInLeft">DustOnLens</h2></a>
 <a href="#"><h2 id="sub6" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInRight">Tilbehöör</h2></a>
 <a href="#"><h2 id="sub7" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInLeft">Coolio</h2></a>
 <a href="#"><h2 id="sub8" class="hidden-h2 animated bounceInRight">?Mystery?</h2></a>
</div>
```

Comment: huge thanks to you! Personally have zero knowlede of js so was struggling with that a lot!

Comment: I'm glad that it proved of use to you. Good luck with the rest of your coding adventure